# Summing Numpy Boolean Indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to find a way to sum an array of values based off of a boolean index, using a modulo function to determine month beginning/end.

```
months = np.arange(36) + 1 # +1 to denote months rather than index
vals = np.ones(36)
vals[12:24] = 2
vals[24:36] = 3

# closest try:

vals.cumsum()[[months % 12 == 0]] # returns array([12, 36, 72])

# target result = array([12, 24, 36])
```

The vals.sum() function just sums the whole thing, but cumsum accumulates over the whole thing, which isn't quite what I'm looking for. Target result is included above - this is a common spreadsheet summarization technique that would usually be done using a SUMIF function to sum values according to certain parameters.

Is there an easy way to do this? I'm sure there is, I'm just missing it and I've put a bit of time trying to get this figured - would prefer not to use a for loop.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need [`np.add.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html):

```
np.add.reduceat(vals, np.flatnonzero((months - 1) % 12 == 0))
# array([ 12.,  24.,  36.])
```

---

*Explanations*:

```
months
# array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
#        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
#        35, 36])
```

1). Use modulo to find out where the condition where the sum should start by `(months - 1) % 12`:

```
(months - 1) % 12 == 0
# array([ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False,
#        False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

2). `np.flatnonzero` is similar to `np.where` and gives the indices, so here, the first sum starts from 0 till 12 (exclusive), etc:

```
np.flatnonzero((months - 1) % 12 == 0)
array([ 0, 12, 24])
```

3). After finding out the indices, use `np.add.reduceat` to sum up the segments:

```
np.add.reduceat(vals, [0, 12, 24])
# array([ 12.,  24.,  36.])
```

Essentially, this is equivalent to `[sum(vals[0:12]), sum(vals[12:24]), sum(vals[24:])]` and gives the output you need.

Comment: Gave you an upvote, but I have less than 15 rep so it doesn't show. This works. Would you mind explaining it? Not sure how the reduce works, and haven't found a clear explanation of flatnonzero.

Comment: Great explanations, thanks. Are you subtracting 1 from months because flatnonzero uses the 0-based indexing rather than the monthly indexing I was trying to use?

Comment: Mostly except it's for `add.reduceat` to work properly since it expects the start index. so `months % 12 == 0` as you did gives the indices where the segment ends, while `(months - 1) % 12 == 0` shifts and gives the indices where the segment starts. I am not completely sure the code above covers all your use cases, you might need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`np.sum(vals[np.where(months % 12 == 0)[0]])` maybe?

`np.where` is used to select the indices.